# How do you turn off monitors individually in Linux, with Nvidia TwinView?

Tags: linux, display, dpms

I frequently watch movies on my computer, but I have two screens. So having something displayed on the other monitor is annoying.

**I currently use this to turn off my monitors:**

```
xset dpms force off
```

I was wondering if there's any way to turn off monitors independently, without having to physically press a button on the monitor, of course.

A program that tells the other monitor to display nothing but black would suffice, but I'd really prefer not to waste the power.

I also have Nvidia TwinView, so applications like `grandr` aren't aware of both monitors as being independent.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Answer (score -1):

I use `grandr` for monitor management.

```
apt-get install grandr
```

It has a handy GUI, which you can start from terminal and offers the functionality you need.

Comment: I'm use Nvidia TwinView and the proprietary nvidia driver, so grandr only sees one screen that's two screens big. It won't work.